# How to generate self closing XML elements using Apache Velocity template, if the value is null or empty

Tags: java, xml, apache, velocity, apache-velocity

Is there any shorter way to generate xml elements using Apache Velocity, with elements with self closing tags if the value is null or empty.

However this can be achieved by putting - #if #else #end.
but I need some shorter way to do this as I need to use it multiple places in template.

```
            #if( $stu.libno )
                <libno>$stu.libno</libno>
            #else
                <libno />
            #end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a good use case for a macro:

```
#macro( optionalTag $tagName $value )
  #if( $value )
    <$tagName>$value</$tagName>
  #else
    <$tagName/>
  #end
#end
```

which you can define at the beginning of your templates, or in the shared global macro library file. Then, you can do:

```
#optionalTag( 'libno', $stu.libno )
```

Comment: Thanks Brisson, This is exactly what I was looking for , however I still get indentation issue with this , but I am sure to find a solution for that as well.